# Суффиксы причастий

Tags: словообразование, суффиксы, причастия

Вопрос в следующем, слово УХОЖЕННЫЙ, почему суффикс ЕНН, если глагол заканчивается на АТЬ, УХАЖИВАТЬ.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что причастие совершенного вида, а глагол несовершенного - из него не выводится этот суффикс. Соответствующие им глагол совершенного вида (уходить) и причастие несовершенного вида (ухаживаемый) почти не употребляются, поэтому для пояснения связей при словообразовании вот другой, близкий по форме пример:

(сов. вид)   омолодить - омолодивший - **омоложенный**

(несов. вид) **омолаживать** - омолаживающий - омолаживаемый

Comment: Спасибо,с этим понятно, только теперь назрел следующий вопрос:от какого глагола образовано причастие УХОЖЕННЫЙ

Comment: Оно не могло образоваться от глагола, поскольку нет однокоренных переходных глаголов, а у него внешние признаки только страдательного причастия. Скорее, слово возникло как прилагательное от существительного "уход".

Comment: Спасибо большое, значит тов. Львову надо быть внимательней при составлении тестов)))

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо,с этим понятно, только теперь назрел следующий вопрос:от какого глагола образовано причастие УХОЖЕННЫЙ

От "уходить". То, что значение корневого морфа совершенно другое, не должно пугать. Такое вообще случается, а тут еще сказалось историческое родство "уходить" и "ухаживать", "выхаживать" и т.д. Сравните с "захаживать" - ныне этот корень считается омонимичным "ухаживать", но в историческом ракурсе это один корень.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, слово "ухоженный" образовано от глагола "уходить", который в данном случае имеет значение не покидать место, а обеспечить ухаживание.

Comment: Спасибо, а то я уже вечер мучаюсь

Comment: Это значение сейчас невозможно, да и грамматический вид у Виктора в объяснениях указан неправильно: не покидать", а "покинуть". Но в цнлом мысль у него совершенно правильная.

Comment: Здесь можно выделить два момента:
1. Связаны ли формой словообразования "уходить" и "ухоженный"? В абстрактном смысле, да: как переходный глагол совершенного вида и образованное от него страдательное причастие совершенного вида.
2. Связаны ли прямым смыслом эти глагол с причастием? Нет. Нельзя сказать: "сад уходили, и потому он теперь ухоженный". Реально употребляемый глагол "уходить" - это непереходный глагол несовершенного вида и имеет значение "покидать место", в то время как "ухоженный" выражает смысл "приведённый в порядок".

Answer (score 0):

Уходить - ухоженный.

Глагол "уходить" многозначный, и в одном из своих значений он является переходным: УХОДИТЬ кого-что, но чаще используется не глагол, а образованное от него страдательное причастие "ухоженный".

Сравнить: Ухаживать за кем-, чем-л., заботиться о ком-, чём-л.  Х. за ранеными.